# Как работать с символами регистра в коде ASCII?

Tags: c#, символы

Я только начал изучать C# и в моём курсе обучения попалась такая вот задача, но, к сожалению, я не могу написать данную программу и поэтому прошу помощи у вас. Помогите пожалуйста с написанием данной программы:

> Числовые значения символов нижнего регистра в коде ASCII отличаются от
>   значении символов верхнего регистра на величину 32. Следовательно, для
>   конвертирования символа нижнего регистра и символ верхнего регистра
>   необходимо вычесть из его значения число 32. Используя эту информацию,
>   напишите программу, которая читает символы, вводимые с клавиатуры.
>   Программа должна конвертировать все символы нижнего регистра в символы
>   верхнего регистра и наоборот, выводя на экран результат. При этом все
>   остальные символы остаются неизменными. Программа должна прекращать
>   работу, когда пользователь вводит символ точки (.). В завершение
>   работы программа должна вывести информацию о количестве измененных
>   символов.

Вопросы:

1. а) Как вычесть число 32 при конвертации символов?
   б) Как должна выглядеть строка кода?
2. Как указать программе верхний регистр и нижний?

**Обновление**

Написал код рабочей программы,
но мне не нравится что каждый символ результата отображается в новой строке.

Вопрос: Как отобразить символы результата в одной строке?

**Обновление 2**

Готовое решение данной задачи.

```
using System;

class Ascii
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int down = 0;
        int up = 0;
        char symbolChar = ' ';
        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite text ispolzuya malenkie i bolshie bukvi");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        while (symbolChar != '.')
        {
            var symbol = Console.Read();

            if (symbol >= 65 && symbol <= 90)
            {
                symbol += 32;
                ++down;
            }
            else if (symbol >= 97 && symbol <= 122)
            {
                symbol -= 32;
                ++up;
            }
            symbolChar = Convert.ToChar(symbol);
            Console.Write(symbolChar);


        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Kolichestvo izmenennih simvolov " + (down + up));
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56750/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: А как с этим: "При этом все остальные символы остаются неизменными." у вас?

Comment: Символы ! + - =  и т. д. остаются неизменными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам набросок того, что должно быть.

```
class Program
{
    //для подсчета кол-ва измененных символов
    private static int _changedSigns;
    //для подсчета кол-ва введенных символов
    private static int _inputedSigns;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //вводимый символ
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите символ: ");
        do
        {
            //считываем
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            //увеличиваем счетчик введенных
            _inputedSigns++;

            string output = AnalizeAndChangeKey(key);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Получилось: {output}");
            Console.WriteLine("Введите еще символ: ");

        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.OemPeriod);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 10));
        Console.WriteLine($"Всего было введено символов: {_inputedSigns}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Всего было изменено символов: {_changedSigns}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string AnalizeAndChangeKey(ConsoleKeyInfo key)
    {
        //для результата
        string result = String.Empty;

        //если символ является буквой
        if (char.IsLetter(key.KeyChar))
        {
            int number = 0;
            char cRes;
            if (char.IsUpper(key.KeyChar))
            {
                //вычисляем по условию задачи
                number = key.KeyChar + 32;
                //преобразуем
                cRes = (char)number;
            }
            else // буква нижнего регистра
            {
                //вычисляем по условию задачи
                number = key.KeyChar - 32;
                //преобразуем
                cRes = (char)number;
            }

            //в результат
            _changedSigns++;
            result = cRes.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //выводим без преобразований
            result = key.KeyChar.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...вероятно требовалось написать решение не прибегая к стандартным методам из `Char`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, вполне может быть. Я написал, что это набросок, а не конечное решение. Автор вопроса может этот момент уточнить у своего преподавателя, и, если требуется, сможет кое-чего исправить самостоятельно.

Comment: Я к сожалению самоучка и учусь по книге "C# учебный курс" Автор Герберт Шилдт.

Comment: @АлексейГригорьев откуда тогда эта задача? И что вам не понятно в моем примере?

Comment: Эта задача из книги, после каждой главы идёт ряд задач и вопросов, и вот только на этой задаче я встал... После этой задаче идут темы Классы, объекты и методы.